# time zone in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My current Oracle SQL Developer is showing time stamps in a different time zone.
I want to match the time zone. My windows time zone is PDT, and this is where I live. The SQL Developer show time stamp in a different time zone, I have to mentally convert that time to PTD.
How to set PDT for SQL Developer?
[image]

Comment: Could you explicitly say Oracle, vs SQL Server, vs MySQL etc...

Comment: @SqlSurfer Oracle. Edited. Thanks!Let me know if you know how.

Comment: Please don't paste pictures, describe your problem as text.

Comment: What is the data type of column `LAST_CNG_DATE`?

Comment: You want the date format in SQLDev to match the date format of your Windows menu/status bar?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I want to match the time zone. My windows time zone is PDT, and this is where I live. The SQL Developer show time stamp in a different time zone, I have to mentally convert that time to PTD.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit TIMESTAMP(3)

Comment: @Lisa i think you need this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006705 - alter session set time_zone

Comment: `TIMESTAMP(3)` - are you sure? In this case you should not see any time zone information at all.

Answer (score 0):

Find `sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf` and add/edit this line:

```
AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=PDT
```

Comment: equivalent to the setenv steps listed here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006705 ...I THINK

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Setting the environment is in fact more generic because it should work in all clients.

Comment: I think `PDT` does not work, check with `SELECT * FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES where tzabbrev = 'PDT';`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I don't really have Oracle here to test. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf12d3/2